# Table - vertical numbering using PHP for cycle

Tags: php, html-table

I need to do some "for" cycle in PHP that will generate table with vertical numbered cells. Here is the image for better understanding:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems have you run into?

Comment: That's nice. Good luck figuring it out. Did you have a question?

Comment: I don't have any idea how to do it, my friend told me I can try it here, sorry for not understanding so much, I'm new here :/

Comment: (Images to show what you need are very welcome here, though we tend to embed them in the question. However a 1700x1500 image is probably a bit large, and could do with being scaled down to 500x350 so it can be embedded efficiently).

Comment: You'll find two nested `for` loops very handy here! Have a look at `php.net/for` to start with. For each cell (since you'll be rendering horizontally not vertically) you'll need to work out how to get the number you need from (x, y, height).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code you're looking for:

```
<?php 
$col = 4;  //number of desired columns 
$row = 5;  //number of desired rows

echo "<table>\n";

for($i = 1; $i<$row+1; $i++)
{
    echo "<tr>\n";
    for($c = 0; $c<$col; $c++)
    {
        echo "<td>".($i + ($c*$row))."</td>\n";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}

echo "</table>\n"
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to achieve something like this

```
<?php 

$x = 0;

echo "<table >";
echo "<tr>";
for($x=1; $x<13; $x++){

echo "<td>$x</td>";
if($x%4 == 0 ){
echo "<tr>"."\n";
}
}
echo "</tr></table>";
?>
```

GOOD LUCK!

Comment: Thanks, I already found better one here, this is just for 4x4 table, I wanted something universal but thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

That will do:

```
<?php
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";

function x($y){
    return ($y<=1)?array($y):array_merge(x($y-1), array($y));
}

function y($x,$z){
    foreach (range($x, count(x($z))) as $i) {
       yield $i;
    }
}

function z($x,$y){
    return array_map(function($w){
        return '<td>'.(1+$w).'</td>';
    }, (iterator_to_array(y($x,$y))));
}

for($i=0;$i<4;$i++){
    echo $i>0?"</tr><tr>":"";
    foreach(z(4*$i, 4*($i+1)-1) as $z) echo $z;
}

echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";

?>
```